# Not able to login in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, login, home-directory

I am in a big trouble. I brought the PC recently with Ubuntu. I tried to partition the drives. I dont know what I did. :(.

When I try switch on the system I get a message like this: `An error occured while mounting /mnt/86e885b7-da67-4784-91d9-4a6e-295f04fe`

`Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery`

**if I press S**

Then it takes me to login. But I am not able to login with my password. I only can login as a guest user. And I can't access `/home`.

**If I press M**

it takes me to the terminal.

Please help me. I don't have any clue. Thanks

**EDITED**

What I did is....

i) I opened `Disks`

ii) selected `home` and clicked on `Unmount the filesystem`

iii) Now the `play` symbol is not coming on the `home` partition

iv) NOw, if I click on `Mount the file system` then it shows like : **`Error mounting filesystem`**    `Not authorized to perform operation (udisks-error-quark, 4)`

v) even `sudo` command is not working

Comment: Your question will need more information before anyone can really help you. See if you can get any further with this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountDevicesTroubleshooting

Comment: @BrianZ .. I have updated something in my question.. please check it

Comment: At least assuming your drive is encrypted, then it sounds like your is a duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/399768/encrypted-disk-wont-unlock-anymore-not-authorized-to-perform-operation-udisks. Try the `udisksctl` commands suggested over there.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting from `sudo`? Could be a permission problem. You may want to have a look at this as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/299384/ubuntu-sudo-not-working

Comment: `sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted`

Comment: I tried `udisksctl` command from your given link. It says `Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda1 is not an encrypted device.`

Comment: `/HOME` is not there under `/etc/fstab` file

Comment: @BrianZ...  Now its working fine.... i have added this line in `etc/fstab`: `LABEL=HOME    /home    ext4    errors=remount-ro 0 1`.

Comment: @BrianZ: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @D'Scolz: Please see Fabby's suggestion, since I don't know how you came to that solution.

Comment: ya sure. I'll update it as answer.

Comment: @Fabby .. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There was an error in my `/etc/fstab`, so I have added this line:

```
LABEL=HOME /home ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

After that I was able to login properly but it was very slow. I was unable to do anything.

Then I tried booting in the recovery mode. There, I got one line like this

```
Repair broken packages
```

Then I clicked on that line and got this message:

```
Continuing will remount your filesystem in read/write mode and mount any other filesystem defined in /etc/fstab
```

then clicked `Yes`.

After that it took around 15 minutes to repair. Now it's good and pretty fast.

Comment: Fantastic first answer!  Congratulations! (and 2 upvotes!)  Please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/584372/revisions) for future reference...  **;-)**